# Javascript array select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my Javascript code, I have a `select` and I add the value of the selected option (for example Volvo) in an array but when the user change the selected option (for example Lamborghini). I want to delete the last selected option in the array and add the newest in that.

How Can I do it ?

For information, I have multiple select option and I call the function `changeClass()`

Thank you for your helps

My HTML code

```
   <select class="form-control" id="car" onchange="changeClass(this)">
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">VW</option>
    <option value="3">Lamborghini</option>
    </select>
```

My Javascript code

```
<script>
    var data = [];
    function changeClass(select) {
        data.push(select.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  If you remove a value and then add another one then you'll only ever have one value in there, so you don't need an array.

Comment: I have other select option so I store all the selected option value in a array and after I will transmit it to my controller in ASP.NET

Comment: Why not just construct the array when you want to send the data?

Comment: I want that the array is dynamic, so when I change the select option it remove the last select option value and add the new one

Comment: Don't tag your question asp-classic when you are using ASP.NET.

Comment: There is no reason to do what you are asking.  Construct the array when you need it.

Comment: Thank you friends ! The solution of @Bala works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in common select function, it will get all selected value into one array

```
   var data;
   $("select").change(function () {
        data = $("select").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        console.log(data)
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7gwf4uab/2/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p72mwqcL/ I want to make like that but it doesn't works, Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply empty the array by re-defining it to empty array:

```
function changeClass(select) {
 data = []; 
 data.push(select.value);
}
```

Comment: I can't do it because I have other select option and I store all the selected option value in the array

Comment: and how do you distinguish which array element points to which select option?

Answer (score 0):

Just use splice to replace the last element with the new one:

```
var arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

arr.splice(arr.length - 1, 1, "ddd");

console.log(arr);
```

logs:

```
["aaa", "bbb", "ddd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the item was added just before the new item then you can do something like this:

```
<script>
  var data = [];
  function changeClass(select) {
    data.pop();
    data.push(select.value);
  }
</script>
```

If you wish to remove the item which was not added just before then you'll have to use event `onfocus`, grab the previously selected value and delete it when `onchange` event is fired.